# HOG descriptor for image processing

Tags: image-processing

I did not find in *Mathematica* a function for [Histogram of Oriented Gradients (HOG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) descriptors.

Is there any similar function?  Do you have an implementation you are willing to share?

Comment: How far have you got with your implementation, `ImageConvolve` might be a good place to start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the *Mathematica* 9 help for `GradientOrientationFilter`:

> Compute the histogram of oriented gradient (HOG) for an image, where each pixel casts a vote weighted by its gradient magnitude in the bin corresponding to its local orientation:

Comment: Yes, this implementation is a bit crude but conveys the idea.